# Python upload file - drop a file in middle of a screen

Tags: python, selenium

I have a website I want to upload file to via python selenium.
Since Im using headless, I cant click the upload file button.
What I can do I drop a file in the center of the screen and it will upload automatically.
I tried to do

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="blocksContainer"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div')
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(element).send_keys("/1file.csv").perform()
```

Didnt work.
This is the website:
[image]

How do we do that?

Comment: Please share the website or source code example, it is impossible to understand with this info. Even maybe you are not passing the valid path data.

Comment: What is `element` ?

Comment: @slckayhn 
Website: https://airtable.com/tbl5bg1KTHPwbaNGL/viwuFGBvFR5yhH7vM?blocks=bligW1dPRmrlIsoEz
logins if needed
lekcol@emailz.co.il 
123456789
I simply try to drop a csv file there on the screen

Comment: @cruisepandey
'element = element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="blocksContainer"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/iframe")'
I sent the website in the comment above if you need to check the elements too

Comment: Please share the relevant code in the question, also I don't see a upload button.

Comment: @cruisepandey what is your element selector? It should be similiar with input[type='file'] css selector.

Comment: @slckayhn

The element that you mean with the input[type='file'] its xpath is:
/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/input
but the program cant locate this xpath element cuz its inside that an iframe. If you find a way to be able to locate that would perfect, but for now I just though simplest way is to make the python bot just drop a file in the middle of this screen in order to upload the file.

Comment: @cruisepandey
Okay, I added the code as you asked.

Comment: @DisplayMoto : I have given the solution in headless mode, do check it out and let me know if you run into any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **explicit waits**, also there is an `iframe` so first you need to `switch to it before sending the keys`, also `no need to click and then upload`, directly do `send_keys`

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path, options = options)
options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2})
options.add_argument('--window-size=1920,1080')
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_settings.cookies": 2})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = driver_path, options = options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://airtable.com/tbl5bg1KTHPwbaNGL/viwuFGBvFR5yhH7vM?blocks=bligW1dPRmrlIsoEz")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "email"))).send_keys("lekcol@emailz.co.il")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "password"))).send_keys("123456789")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[class^='signInButton']"))).click()

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[allow^='geolocation']")))
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='file']").send_keys("C:\\Users\\***\\****\\Desktop\\CSV-FILE.csv")

print('Done')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Checking now. I believe yours will work
May I know how did you locate the CSS_SELECTOR
<pre> "input[type='file']" <code> which element you located, I couldnt find it

Comment: yeah it is there you need to open dev tool by pressing F12, then go  to Element section, and do Control + F, a search bar will appear, then write `input[type='file']`, you would see 1/1 matches. also regarding locate, css is written like this : - `tagname[attribute_name='attribute_value']`, that's how I wrote it. Main thing was that it was in iframe, so had to switch over it.

Comment: Let me know if you face any issue while running this code ?

Comment: Yes. It's working! Just one thing- how can we do
.send_keys("/1file.csv") instead of writing the full path?
(The file is in the same folder of the script)

Comment: try this line `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='file']").send_keys(cwd = os.getcwd()+ "\\csvfile_1.csv")`

Comment: Gives this error:
send_keys() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cwd'

Comment: I think that is cause of import, `import os ` try this

Comment: imported, same. it doesn't identify the 'cwd'

Comment: oh man it was a typo, `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='file']").send_keys(os.getcwd()+ "\\csvfile_1.csv")` try this with `import os`